# HMAC_SHA1 differ on PHP and Lua

Tags: php, lua, hmacsha1

I'm trying to generate a HMAC_SHA1 in php, and validate it in openresty lua

PHP Code:

```
$hmac_sha1 = hash_hmac('sha1', 'test', 'gabri', true);
echo base64_encode($hmac_sha1);
```

Which produces:

```
/ReAJgDe67/lF3BNbaGSCx70J/c=
```

And the same code in lua:

```
local hmac_sha1 = ngx.hmac_sha1("test", "gabri")
ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE,  ngx.encode_base64(hmac_sha1) );
```

produces:

```
Yczcenrc2EAOpfm9UEWwME9XLRI=
```

Why are they different?

In PHP, I've included the 4th parameter on hash_hmac, which return the data as raw binary

As per:
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxhmac_sha1

> The raw binary form of the HMAC-SHA1 digest will be generated, use
>   ngx.encode_base64, for example, to encode the result to a textual
>   representation if desired.

Comment: Suspect one of this function returns value as binary string and one as hex string.

Comment: Looks like PHP is wrong, as per nginx documentation, 

_local key = "thisisverysecretstuff"_
_local src = "some string we want to sign"_
_local digest = ngx.hmac_sha1(key, src)_
_ngx.say(ngx.encode_base64(digest))_

yields the output

_R/pvxzHC4NLtj7S+kXFg/NePTmk=_

 - But in PHP:

_$key = "thisisverysecretstuff";_
_$src = "some string we want to sign";_
_$digest = hash_hmac('sha1', $key, $src, true);_
_echo base64_encode($digest);_

yields

_y2h0PgNY9Xfil5xe6wCXLhTcPZI=_

Comment: $digest = hash_hmac('sha1', $src, $key, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According docs

`string hash_hmac(string $algo, string $data, string $key [, bool $raw_output = false])`
`digest = ngx.hmac_sha1(secret_key, str)`

So in `hash_hmac('sha1', 'test', 'gabri', true);` `test` is data and `gabri` is key.
But in `ngx.hmac_sha1("test", "gabri")` `gabri` is data and `test` is key